# Python: check for a KeyError in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

Is there a way that I can write the following in a single line without causing a KeyError if `entries` is not present in `mydict`?

```
b = [i for i in mydict['entries'] if mydict['entries']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dict.get()` to default to an empty list if the key is missing:

```
b = [i for i in mydict.get('entries', [])]
```

In your version, the `if` filter only applies to each iteration as if you nested an `if` statement under the `for` loop:

```
for i in mydict['entries']:
    if mydict['entries']:
```

which isn't much use if `entries` throws a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
b = [i for i in mydict.get('entries', [])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
b = [i for i in mydict.get('entries', [])]
```

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to do this, `Dict.setdefault`.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(
... )
'Thu May  1 18:11:53 2014'
>>> d = {}
>>> a = d.setdefault('time',time.ctime())
>>> a
'Thu May  1 18:12:17 2014'
>>> d
{'time': 'Thu May  1 18:12:17 2014'}
>>>
```